# NIntegrate over elliptic region with and without a constant term

Tags: numerical-integration

While working with NIntegrate and adding a constant term in the integrand to avoid errors for zero-integrals, i find that the results with and without the addition are different in general. Below is the code that states the problem:

```
Clear[f1, f2, const, Int1, Int2, Tab1, Tab2, x, y, a, R];


a = 1;
area[R_] := NIntegrate[Boole[x^2/(a^2*R^2) + y^2/R^2 <= 1] 1, {x, -a*R, a*R}, {y, -R, R}]

const = 10;

f1[x_, y_] := (8 x^2*a^3 (x^2 + a^2))/(π*((x^2 + a^2)^2 + 4 y^2*x^2*a^2)^2)
f2[x_, y_] := const + f1[x,y]

Int1[R_] := NIntegrate[Boole[x^2/(a^2*R^2) + y^2/R^2 <= 1] f1[x, y], {x, -a*R, a*R}, {y, -R, R}]
Int2[R_] := NIntegrate[Boole[x^2/(a^2*R^2) + y^2/R^2 <= 1] f2[x, y], {x, -a*R, a*R}, {y, -R, R}]

Tab1 = Table[{R, Int1[R]}, {R, 17, 19, 0.01}];
Tab2 = Table[{R, Int2[R] - const*area[R]}, {R, 17, 19, 0.01}];


ListLinePlot[{Tab1, Tab2}, PlotRange -> Full, PlotLabel -> "RL", AxesLabel -> {R}, PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thick}, {Red, Thick}},PlotLegends -> Framed[LineLegend[{Blue, Red}, {1, 2}]]]
```

And it gives following output:

[image]

It would be extremely helpful if someone can explain as to what is wrong with it?

Comment: This looks like a "catastrophic cancellation" type error.  `NIntegrate`, as a numerical function, won't give a perfect result.  It has some limits on relative precision (`PrecisionGoal`) to constrain computation time.  `area` and `Int2` are both on the order of $10^4$, and when you subtract them you get a result on the order of $1$.  You are losing 4 orders of magnitude of relative precision.  I would reduce the magnitude of additive term to control cancellation errors.  Alternatively (or in addition to this) I would try to play with `PrecisionGoal`.

Comment: Indeed I find that using `PrecisionGoal -> 10` removes the difference between the two curves.

Comment: "adding a constant term in the integrand to avoid errors for zero-integrals" -- If I understand your goal, I usually manage this with an appropriately chosen finite `AccuracyGoal`. The example given does not seem to be of this type, so one cannot check whether this approach would work for you.